# NodeJs + Async + Google auth + passport + aws-ssm

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, google-authentication, aws-ssm

I am using nodejs and implemented the google-auth using passport npm module.
But I am fetching google api-key and secret-key fetching from the aws:ssm parameter like server call..

But the problem is we needs to parse the api-key and secret-key when passport initialize..
I am not sure how to fetch those keys before passport initialize 
I added promise function only for fetch the client id for testing. I am not sure how to call async call  when initialize. 
I attached the sample code:

```
var passport = require('passport');
var GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth').OAuthStrategy;

const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const ssm = new AWS.SSM();

const getClientId = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  const params = {
    Name: 'xxx',
    WithDecryption: false
  };
  ssm.getParameter(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('-----------', err)
      reject(err);
    } else {
      resolve(data);
    }
  });
});

var clientid = getClientId();

passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    consumerKey: clientid, //(needs to fetch from aws-ssm)
    consumerSecret: GOOGLE_CONSUMER_SECRET, //(needs to fetch from aws-ssm)
    callbackURL: "http://localhost:8080/auth/google/callback"
  },
  function(token, tokenSecret, profile, done) {
     return done(null,profile);
  }
));

module.exports { passport : passport }
```

router code I have in different file

```
app.get('/auth/google',
  passport.authenticate('google', { scope: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login'] }));

app.get('/auth/google/callback', 
  passport.authenticate('google', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
  function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('/');
  });
```

Can someone help me to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Since passport depends on Asynchronous task, instead of requiring `passport`, you need to pass it as an argument from Main Application, and just export the function.

You can await till you get the client ID and other required info.

> passport_init.js

```
var GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth').OAuthStrategy;

const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const ssm = new AWS.SSM();

const getClientId = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  const params = {
    Name: 'xxx',
    WithDecryption: false
  };
  ssm.getParameter(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('-----------', err)
      reject(err);
    } else {
      resolve(data);
    }
  });
});

// Passport as argument passed from Main Application
module.exports = async function(passport) {
    var clientid = await getClientId();

    passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
        consumerKey: clientid, //(needs to fetch from aws-ssm)
        consumerSecret: GOOGLE_CONSUMER_SECRET, //(needs to fetch from aws-ssm)
        callbackURL: "http://localhost:8080/auth/google/callback"
      },
      function(token, tokenSecret, profile, done) {
         return done(null,profile);
      }
    ));
}
```

Main Application:

> app.js / routes.js

```
const passport = require('passport');

// Pass passport as argument
let initPassport = require('./config/passport_init.js');
initPassport(passport)
    .then(() => {
        console.log('Passport Initialised successfully');

        app.get('/auth/google',
          passport.authenticate('google', { scope: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login'] }));

        app.get('/auth/google/callback', 
          passport.authenticate('google', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
          function(req, res) {
            res.redirect('/');
          });

    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```